# El método winfo_patchname() da error

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Quiero obtener la ruta del widget Button, pero me devuelve un error:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Main Window")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Click here")
button.pack()

root.update()  # Wait for the widget to be fully created

# Wait 100ms to give time for the widget to create its window ID
root.after(100)

path = root.winfo_pathname(button.winfo_id())
print(f"The full path of the button is: {path}")

root.mainloop()
```

salida en la consola:
_tkinter.TclError: window id "15664426" doesn't exist in this application

Answer (score 0):

El error que estás recibiendo se debe a que el widget `Button` aún no ha sido completamente creado antes de llamar al método `winfo_pathname()`. Para solucionar este problema puedes agregar una llamada a `root.update_idletasks()` justo antes de la llamada a `root.after(100)`, lo que garantizará que el widget `Button` se haya creado completamente antes de intentar acceder a su información de ruta.

Aquí está el código actualizado:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Main Window")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Click here")
button.pack()

root.update()  # Wait for the widget to be fully created
root.update_idletasks()  # <- Esta línea es la nueva

# Wait 100ms to give time for the widget to create its window ID
root.after(100)

path = root.winfo_pathname(button.winfo_id())
print(f"The full path of the button is: {path}")

root.mainloop()
```